# Solving recurrence relations using characteristics root techinque

Tags: discrete-mathematics

During solving recurrence relations using characteristics root techinque why do we assume $F(n) = r^n$?

Comment: The short answer: because it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have the equation
$$
(S-r_1)(S-r_2)\cdots(S-r_k)\,a_n=0\tag1
$$
where $Sa_n=a_{n+1}$ is the shift operator on sequences, then we have the $k$ solutions to
$$
(S-r_j)\,a_n=0\tag2
$$
and since $(2)$ is $a_{n+1}=r_ja_n$, the solution to $(2)$ is pretty clearly $a_n=c_jr_j^n$.

Thus,
$$
a_n=\sum_{j=1}^kc_jr_j^n\tag3
$$
is a solution to $(1)$, but since $k$ initial values fix $a_n$, varying the $k$ $c_j$s gives all the solutions.