# Intuition behind solution of recurrence relations using z transforms or characteristic polynomials

Tags: recurrence-relations

Consider, for instance, the gambler ruins problem:

https://www1.cmc.edu/pages/faculty/Bhunter/GamblersRuin.pdf

Let $p_k$ be the probability of achieving the maximum $N$ dollars when we have initially $k$ dollars.

The recurrence for $p_k$ is given by

\begin{equation}
p_k = a p_{k+1} + bp_{k-1}
\end{equation}
where $a$ and $b$ are the probabilities or winning and losing 1 dollar, per round, respectively. We have $p_0=0$ and $p_N=1$.

The characteristic root equation is derived from
\begin{equation}
\sum p_k s^k = \sum a p_{k+1} s^k + \sum bp_{k-1} s^k
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\sum p_k s^k = \sum a p_{k} s^{k-1} +    \sum b p_{k} s^{k+1}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\sum p_k s^{k+1} = \sum a p_{k} s^{k} +    \sum b p_{k} s^{k+2}
\end{equation}
i.e.,
\begin{equation}
s = a  +  b s^{2}
\end{equation}

1. is there a simple way to relate the solution to the problem using z transform and the solution using the characteristic root equation?
2. is there an intuitive way to understand that if $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of the characteristic root equation, then $p_k = C_1 r_1^k + C_2 r_2^k$?
3. can we say that the z transform method and the characteristic root equation method are in reality the same method?

(This question is a follow up to [Solving recurrence relations using characteristics root techinque](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469331/solving-recurrence-relations-using-characteristics-root-techinque) and [How to prove the characteristic equation based solution of recurrence relations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243033/how-to-prove-the-characteristic-equation-based-solution-of-recurrence-relations))

Comment: See also [Proof for the formula of the $n^{th}$ term of a linear and homogeneous second-order recurrence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198351/proof-for-the-formula-of-the-n-textth-term-of-a-linear-and-homogeneous-seco), and my answer [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4198621/291201) for an entirely elementary way to derive #2. Basic idea is that you can find a linear combination of consecutive terms $p_{k+1}$ and $p_{k}$ that satisfy a first order recurrence i.e. form a geometric progression.